# How to trim video in android (without ffmpeg)?

Tags: android, video, trim

Hi I am trying to trim video in android, but all of the source codes I have found are using ffmpeg, is there a smaller library, which I can use ?
Because ffmpeg library is about 8-9 MB, and my application is about 6 MB, adding ffmpeg library to my app will make it more than double size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [mp4parser](http://mp4parser.googlecode.com/) library. Have a look at the `ShortenExample` it does exactly what the name suggests. Since the library cannot re-encode the video it can only cut the video at I-frames. So the points in time where you can make a cut are quite coarse.

On Android 4.1 you can access the hardware codecs via MediaCodec API which could be an option (but I haven't seen any example of that yet)

Or, you can use this class: [TrimVideoUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-4.2.1_r1.2/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/TrimVideoUtils.java)